# Android Studio: Can't load Build.gradle page to change Gradle version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

1) imported android samples into android studio 0.5.1

2) using Mac, OS X 10.9.2

3) prompted to change Gradle version to 1.10 and plug-in to 0.9

4) changed gradle.properties in projectName.iml file

5) build.gradle remains blank even though I double click in to project folder

6) it's error msg: Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly.

7) How can I get build.gradle to show so I can change version and plugin? I tried pasting code from build.gradle in test folder, but then that causes other problems.

Thanks for your help!
Eliza

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! Please give more details on your issue, setup, environement... And try to avoid external links, ideally every question should be able to stand alone.

Comment: Have you tried closing AndroidStudio and opening it again?

Comment: Late reply. Thank you both! Robin noted re: external links. Did try to open and close. Looks like I was trying to work in the blank gradle page which comes with every project. My bad. The one in the inner project folder is the real one. Thanks.